# Android: ListView not displaying as intended?

Tags: android, xml, listview, loops, dictionary

In the following code I intend to produce both an ouput on the item line and the subitem line but the code is just bringing me up an empty listview. How can I rectify this?

The game is a multiplication times tables game with the intention that when the user enters answers (on prev activity) the answer they entered are shown in the item (i.e. 12 items) and the correct answer for each is shown in each sub-item.

.Java code:

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.results);

        ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvresults);


        //gets array from prev act
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");

        int numberPassed = getIntent().getIntExtra("numberPassed", 0);


        ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > list = new ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > ();


        // loop to give list view
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
        {
            int userAnswer = results[i - 1];

            int expectedAnswer = numberPassed * i;

            String userString = numberPassed + "x" + i + "=" + userAnswer;

            String expectedString = "" + expectedAnswer;

            HashMap <String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String> ();

            map.put("user", userString);
            map.put("expected", expectedString);

            list.add(map);
        }


        String[] keys = {"user", "expected"};

        int[] ids = {R.id.user_answer, R.id.expected_answer};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);

        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/lvresults"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expected_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] ids={android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2}
```

and remove the two TextView from the layout

Comment: How do i then implement this in the simpleAdapter?